# trying to improve performance of a join in SQL query

Tags: sql, join, ssms-2012

I have somewhat of an "ugly" situation and this slows down my query significantly. I have two tables I'm trying to join...

Table1

```
ID          Val1          Val2         Data1         Data2
1           123           BAL          Apple         California
2           345           NAL          Microsoft     Washington
3           566           HAO          Google        New York
```

Table2

```
ID          Val         Ind          Data     
1           123-BAL       Y            Some value
2           566-HAO       N            Other value
```

My query looks like this:

```
Select * from Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 on (t1.Val1 + '-' + t1.Val2) = t2.Val and Ind = 'Y'
```

DESIRED RESULT:

```
ID          Val1          Val2         Data1         Data2
1           123           BAL          Apple         California
```

But this query is extremely slow. I cannot change the indexes on the tables, but is there another way I can re-write this query to improve performance. It's not a perfect situation but any improvement would be helpful.

Comment: *(1)*  What do you mean by "extremely slow"? *(2)* Please share the execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ *(3)* What is the cardinality of each table?

Comment: Can you create views, specifically [indexed views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15)? A view created from `Table1` with an index on `Val1 + '-' + Val2` ought to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
Select *
from Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2 
     ON (t1.Val1 + '-' + t1.Val2) = t2.Val and t2.Ind = 'Y';
```

I think this will take advantage of an index on `table2(Ind, Val)`.  But, you might also want to try an index in `Table1`.  To do this, define a computed column, create an index, and then use the column in the query:

```
alter table table1 add val as (t1.Val1 + '-' + t1.Val2) persisted;

create index idx_table1_val on table1(val);
Select *
from Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2 
     ON t1.Val = t2.Val and t2.Ind = 'Y';
```

Comment: "I cannot change the indexes on the tables"